# How to avoid "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error when file might be empty?

Tags: .net, powershell

I want to open a file, replace some content, and append to another file. I wrote a Powershell script:

```
(Get-Content file.txt).replace("abc", "def") | Add-Content other.txt
```

This works fine, unless file.txt is empty. Then it gives an error

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Why does it give that error? And how can I avoid it?

I expected opening an empty file to return empty rather than null, as it would in unix

```
cat file.txt | sed -r s/abc/def/g >> other.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use PowerShell's `-Replace` **operator** instead of the `Replace` method of the returned `String` (being null for an empty file).

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -Replace "abc", "def" | Add-Content other.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
(Get-Content file.txt).replace("abc", "def") | Add-Content other.txt -erroraction SilentlyContinue
```

There are other options for the type of `erroraction`, so just use tab completion to view them and test them if SilentlyContinue does not do what you're looking for!

EDIT: If you need to know that something has failed because it is empty, please view Bernard's answer. Otherwise this one liner should work as well, just depends on what your needs are.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = "\test.txt"
$path2 = "\test2.txt"

try{
    $content = (Get-Content $path).replace("abc", "def") | Add-Content $path2
    Write-Host "Successfully added content" -ForegroundColor Green
}catch{
    if(!$content){
        Write-Host "$path is empty" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }else{
        throw $_
    }
}
```

I think you should always work with try/catch when running cmdlets..

Hope this helps